# PDFBox invalid option in radio

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox, acrofields

When trying to fill the form of this pdf (http://vaielab.com/Test/2.pdf) with this code

```
PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("2.pdf"));
pdfDocument.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
if (acroForm != null) {             
    PDField field = (PDField) acroForm.getField("rad2");
    try {
        field.setValue("0");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
pdfDocument.save("output.pdf");
pdfDocument.close();
```

I get this error: value '0' is not a valid option for the field rad2, valid values are: [Yes] and Off

But value "0" should be a valid option, and if I do a dump_data_fields with pdftk, I get this:

```
FieldType: Button
FieldName: rad2
FieldFlags: 49152
FieldJustification: Left
FieldStateOption: 0
FieldStateOption: 1
FieldStateOption: Off
FieldStateOption: Yes
```

I also tried the value "1" but get the exact same error.

I'm using pdfbox 2.0.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the `Opt` values in `Root/AcroForm/Fields/[7]/Opt`, that one has two "Yes" entries only. The `PDButton.setValue()` code in PDFBox updates this field differently when `/Opt` is set. The best here would be not to set it, or remove these entries by calling `field.setExportValues(null)` . Then valid settings would be 0, 1 and "Off".

[image: PDFDebugger screenshot of the field]

Comment: Thank you for the information. By the way, could you tell me what software did you use to get this image? Thanks again

Comment: PDFBox PDFDebugger app. Get it from the download site :-)